# Randomforest clasification : How to infer class probability from "probabilityCol"

Tags: apache-spark, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

**Background:**

I am running a random-forest classifier on a dataFrame with label classes as [0,1] . My goal is to extract the probability of label '1' from the *probabilityCol* column.

As per the [spark ml docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/ml-classification-regression.html#output-columns-predictions),

> ***probabilityCol***  Vector of length # classes equal to rawPrediction normalized to a multinomial distribution

**Question**:

1. What is the ordering of the target classes within the vector *probabilityCol* ? Can we even determine the same ?
2. Incase i want to extract the possibility of a given class ('1' in my case), what is the recommended way for extracting the same.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) The ordering corresponds to the numeric values of labelCol (your target column name). In probability vector class '0' always goes first, then goes class '1' etc. RandomForest works only with numeric class values, so they always act like indexes.

2) Suppose you have dataframe **prediction** with column **probability**. To get the probability for class 1 you can use UDF function:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val classNum = 1

def getTop(x : DenseVector) : Double = {
    x.toArray(classNum)
}
val udfGetTop = udf(getTop _)

val predictionTop = prediction
  .select("labelIndexed", "probability")
  .withColumn("label1Prob", udfGetTop($"probability"))
```